# Should un-publishing a pdf that is used in a component on page cause the page to be unpublished?

Tags: tridion

We are handling PDF publishing by using a Dynamic Component Template associated with the PDF schema, then creating Binary Links where we need to link to the PDF.

We've found that un-publishing a PDF that is a component link inside a component used on a page is triggering the page to get unpublished.

I know we can control this behaviour by using a Custom Resolver, but is this the expected result?

Has this behaviour changed from Tridion 2009 to Tridion 2011?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BinaryLinks are meant to be used for "inline binary content", so typically things that are included by a src attribute.

```
<img src="..." />
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For this inline binary content, the page will not display correctly without it. Knowing that, it is correct that the Page gets unpublished when you unpublish the MMC. So as far as I can tell this is indeed the expected behavior, which hasn't changed in a long time.

The mistake is in using an MMC for a PDF that you want to show as a hyperlink. For anything that you want to link to (so that turns into a <a href="...") you should be using a ComponentLink (or of course a PageLink of it is a Page).

Comment: What we've found is that a Component Link will not resolve, as the PDF is not actually on a page anywhere, but instead published to the server with Dynamic Template. A Binary Link however will return an anchor tag pointing to the PDF.

Comment: We use the Add Binary method, like this:

engine.AddBinary(binary.Id, template.Id, null, binary.BinaryContent.GetByteArray(),CreateUniqueBinaryName(binary));

Comment: Hmmm.... how about using RenderComponentPresentation from the DWT? Otherwise creating a Publish instruction for the MMC or a custom resolver to include the MMC in the same publish action should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The unpublishing of items that are used by a Binary Component was already there in 2009 (so much so, it's even one of the questions of the Tridion 2009 Business Analyst Exam).

I see a trend developing of people using Dynamic Component Presentations for their binaries, which bypasses all this side effect, but leaves you potentially with bad binary links on your pages.

If you go down the DCP route for binaries, make sure to use Dynamic Linking (pretty simple to create on the CM by using "tridion:type=binary" in your anchor markup).

Comment: The tridion:type="Binary" creates a link that works, but still has the side effect of causing the page to be unpublished when the Binary is, as it just generates a BinaryLink tag as far i can tell? The documentation says "If you unpublish a Component, any Components that link to that Component are not unpublished." I guess this behaviour is different for Binary's, so we will need a custom resolver here?

Comment: The problem is that you're calling AddBinary and not publishing a separate Component Presentation. A custom resolver indeed sounds best and may well be simpler than creating a custom PublishInstruction.

Comment: If you use tridion:type=binary you are indeed expected to publish your binary by other means - DCP typically - instead of using AddBinary or any other variation of it. A Custom Resolver or calling RenderCP from within the DWT will take care of that.